# fr3d LdapBundle - preventing login

Tags: php, symfony-2.1, fr3dldapbundle

I am using LDAP to authenticate my users (with fallback to FOS User Bundle). Everything works fine, I can log in.

This has, however created a "new" problem. I wish to control who can log into the application using FOS, but control their password using LDAP.

I tried this using ROLES:

```
- { path: ^/, role: ROLE_PGM_USER }
```

but that isn't the right place as the user has already logged in at this point.

Is there a way to configure fr3d to also check the fos "enabled" field and then display a custom message if they are not allowed to log in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

Use the instructions here to override the LdapManager (https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/cookbook/override_ldap-manager.md).

Then change the bind function like so:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function bind(LdapUserInterface $user, $password)
{
    if (!$user->hasRole('ROLE_PGM_USER')) {
        return false;
    }
    return $this->connection->bind($user->getDn(), $password);
}
```

This way users without "ROLE_PGM_USER" are prevented from logging in.